# Free module over $M_n(\mathbb Q)$ has all its bases of the same cardinality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Show that a free module over $M_n(\mathbb Q)$ has all its bases of the same cardinality.

$M_n(\mathbb Q)$ is of finite length as $\mathbb Q$ is of finite length, but this fact is not leading me anywhere.
Or something if the bases over $M_n(\mathbb Q)$ can be made bases over $\mathbb Q$ then it's good!!

Comment: Is $Q$ the field of rationals?

Comment: Yes Q denotes rational

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As $M_n(\Bbb Q)$ has dimension $n^2$ as a vector space over $\Bbb Q$, then
a rank $r$ free module over $M_n(\Bbb Q)$ has dimension $rn^2$ as a vector
space over $\Bbb Q$. Therefore $r$ is uniquely defined.

This argument works for all finite-dimensional algebras over fields.

Comment: What if the rank is not finite???

Comment: @NitinTomar Still no problem.... think elementary cardinal arithmetic.

Comment: Ok thank a lot !!!